How can I express this expectation as something I'm able to calculate?
Consider a queue with one server and infinitely many customers already, and a time-varying service rate $\mu(t)$. I want to get a closed expression for the expected time it takes to finish serving $n$ customers. How should I tackle this? Here is my thought.
$K(\tau): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is defined as number of customers served during $[0, \tau]$. Notice the whole function $K(\tau)$ depends on the samples $\omega \in \Omega$. For a specific $\omega \in \Omega$,  $K$ is obviously piecewise constant, nondecreasing and right-continuous, with jump sizes 1. We know given $\tau$, $K(\tau)$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\bar{\mu}_{0, \tau} := \int_{0}^{\tau} \mu(t)dt$, in other words, $\mathbb{P}[ K(\tau) = m ] = e^{-\bar{\mu}_{0, \tau}} \frac{\bar{\mu}_{0, \tau}^{m}}{m!}, m = 0, 1, ...$.
Now, the smallest time it takes to serve $n$ customers should be $\inf \{K^{-1}(n)\}$, so what I'm asking for is
\begin{align*}
    \int \inf \{K^{-1}(n)\}(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega)
\end{align*}
where $\omega$ represents the elements in the sample space $\Omega$. Now how should I proceed to write the above integral as something I can calculate? Or, should I have started another way? Appreciate any help!

If you know $\mu(t)$ then you can just integrate that, ie. find an upper limit of integration such that the integral equals $n$.

@msantama During any $[t, t+s]$, the number of customers served is a Poisson random variable with mean $\int_{t}^{t+s}\mu(x)dx$, instead of a constant which equals $\int_{t}^{t+s}\mu(x)dx$. So if I solve for $y$ such that $\int_{t}^{t+y}\mu(x)dx = n$, what does this $y$ represent? Are you saying $y$ actually is the mean amount of time needed?

A non-homogenous Poisson process with intensity function $\mu(t)$ is characterized by the property
$$N(t + s) - N(s) \sim \text{Poisson}\left( \int_{t}^{t + s} \mu(x) \, \text{d}x \right)$$
for all $t \geq s \geq 0$ and $N(0) = 0$. Therefore, for any $t \geq 0$
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ N(t) \right] = \int_{0}^{t} \mu(x) \, \text{d}x$$
Consider two questions:

What is the expected time to serve $n$ customers?
How long does it take to serve $n$ customers in expectation?

The answer to the second question is found by solving
$$n = \int_{0}^{t} \mu(x) \, \text{d}x$$
Now convince yourself the two questions are asking the exact same thing.
